# What is the use of the key property in useFetch composable options (Nuxt3)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

i'm new to nuxt3 and i don't understand the role (use) of `key` option in [useFetch](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/use-fetch/#example) composable

it says ;

```
/*
key: a unique key to ensure that data fetching can be properly de-duplicated across requests
if not provided, it will be generated based on the url and fetch options
*/
```

can someone give a simplified idea)
thanks in advance

Comment: i'm not sure but i think it's something related to caching

Answer (score 2):

The biggest clue is in comment you posted. The key word is de-duplicate/d

/ (diːˈdjuːplɪˌkeɪt) / verb. (tr) computing to remove (duplicated material) from a system.

So it is used to prevent the data from being fetched more than once between the server and client as part of the Hydration.

I believe but stand to be corrected that when hydrating a server-rendered page the key is used to map the result of the server-side to the client-side component data.